# Why can't I use a typeglob in the diamond operator in Perl?

Tags: perl

Usually bareword as the filehanle or a variable holds filehandle could be places inside `<>` operator to reference the file, but **NOT** the filehandle extracted from typeglob as the last line below shows. Why it doesn't work because the last case also references a filehandle?

```
open FILE, 'file.txt';
my $myfile = *FILE{IO};
print <$myfile>;
print <*FILE{IO}>; # this line doesn't work.
```

Comment: Worth noting that for good style, 3 argument open with lexical filehandles is generally a better style, because it avoids all sorts of problems (this one included)

Comment: The only good reason to use Bareword file handles is for compatibility with the Perl 4 interpereter you found on an archeological dig.  Don't get me wrong.  I loved Perl 4 in it's time.

Comment: You're also missing a semicolon on line 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2FO-Operators), it says:

> If what's within the angle brackets is neither a filehandle nor a
>   simple scalar variable containing a filehandle name, typeglob, or
>   typeglob reference, it is interpreted as a filename pattern to be
>   globbed ...

Since we want to be able to say things like:

```
foreach (<*.c>) {
  # Do something for each file that matches *.c
}
```

it is not possible for perl to interpret the '*' as meaning a typeglob.

As noted in the other answer, you can work around this using readline, or you can assign the typeglob to a scalar first (as your example shows).

Comment: Or better yet - don't use typeglob filehandles, and exclusively used lexicals.

Answer (score 6):

`<>` is among other things shortcut for [`readline()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html), and it accepts simple scalars or bare word, ie. `<FILE>`. For more complex expressions you have to be more explicit,

```
print readline *FILE{IO};
```

otherwise it will be interpreted as [`glob()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)

```
perl -MO=Deparse -e 'print <*FILE{IO}>;'

use File::Glob ();
print glob('*FILE{IO}');
```

Comment: So why `readline` works for both `*FILE{IO}` and `$foo`, but its shortcut `<>` can only work with the latter?

Comment: @Thomson check update. `<>` can have more meanings, depending on context.